# jquery replace only text in a div with other tags in it

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains text and other tags in it

```
<div id="Field"><span> </span>Text to replace<div ></div></div>
```

I can not change the structure of the div.

How can I change only the "Text to replace" using jquery?

EDIT:
Perhaps I should have mentioned that the "Text to replace" is dynamic and I have no idea what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#Field').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Text to replace','Hi I am replace');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Field"><span> </span>Text to replace<div ></div></div>
```

Comment: I used the textContent to change it fully without knowing the text behind. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
​$("#Field").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Text to replace", "Your Data"); 
});​​​​​
```

Comment: It is always good to add a little bit of explanation. Instead of just providing solutions.

Comment: @dryleaf the solutions is pretty straightforward. Don't think this needs a description.